Cassandra JVM getting random OOM during writes
I had recently changed Cassandra GC from G1GC to zGC (JDK 11). P99 latencies had improved a lot,but during writes I am seeing randomly some nodes are getting restarted due to JVM OOM. CPU usage is below 50%. Please provide your suggestions if anyone has faced similar issue when ZGC is used.

max heap size: 38 GB
max direct memory size: 38 GB
RAM: 125 GB
CPU: 32
concurrent_reads: 32

JVM settings:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseZGC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:ConcGCThreads=16"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=9"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=25"

JVM error message:
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f077cd64df4, pid=2341073, tid=2342488
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (11.0.22+7) (build 11.0.22+7-LTS)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (11.0.22+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, z gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0xbf4df4]  Node::rematerialize() const+0x4


So I have been testing out ZGC with a Cassandra 4.1.6 cluster, and been seeing the same type of errors. ZGC is an experimental feature in java 11, and I strongly believe the error you are seeing is due to it being an experimental  feature. Upgrading to Cassandra 5.0.x allows you to run ZGC in java 17 (ZGC was promoted to a Feature in Java 15). I think running ZGC at least for production is not recommended.
Not sure if this answers your question, but at least it is an indicator why you are seeing this error.
